# Understanding the CSS child selector >

Tags: html, css-selectors

In my tests, styles for a `div > ul` rule are also applied to `div ul li ul` elements. Why is the `>` child selector not always enforced?

I have a solution for this, but I want to understand why I need to use this solution.

In CSS, I understand that `a b` will select every element that matches `b` which is a descendant of an element that matches `a`. The `a` element can appear anywhere in the hierarchy above the `b` element.

I thought I understood that `a > b` will select only elements that match `b` if they are the immediate child of an element that matches `a`. The `a` element must be the direct parent of the `b` element.

However, in the test below, the style `font-weight: bold;` is applied to all `ul` items, even those that are not the immediate children of the `div` element. To prevent the style from being applied, I need to first set a conflicting style, as I do with the `color` property.

What is the logic in the CSS that makes it work the way it does?

```css
div ul {
  color: black;
}
div > ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>red and BOLD 1</li>
    <li>red and BOLD 2</li>
    <li>red and BOLD 3
      <ul>
        <li>black and BOLD 1</li>
        <li>black and BOLD 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>red and BOLD 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tts7x7gz/)

Comment: The font property is inherited. See http://jsfiddle.net/tts7x7gz/1/ and then remove the `>`  in `div > ul`. See also http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect isn't the result of the child selector. What you are seeing is a result of [property inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance).

The value of a property in CSS is defined by 3 rules:

1. If the cascade (basically, this boils down to "what is defined by CSS files and your browser") explicitly specifies a value, use that.
2. If the property has an inherited value and is not in the root of the DOM, use the parent's value for that property.
3. Otherwise, use the property's pre-defined initial value.

Some properties, if a value isn't defined in the cascade, are automatically assigned a value of 'inherit'. For the nested `ul` element, you didn't define a value for `font-weight`, and `font-weight` is [one of those properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) that defaults to `inherit` (notice the "inheritance" entry in the table at the top), so it will use whatever its parent element is using (which you've defined to be bold).

Your selector is accurately selecting only the direct children, but the rule is being inherited by the children's children because that's how that particular property behaves. A property which is not inherited by default would not affect the children.

```css
#parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span id="parent">
  All of the text in here is bold,
  <span id="child">
    even the text in the child.
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The *default* value for `font-weight` and `color` (for `ul` and `li` elements) is [`inherit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#valdef-all-inherit).

So your rule only applies to the child `ul` element (setting the `font-weight` to `bold`) and then the `li` element inherits that value.

If you had an `a` element with an `href` element inside one of the list items then it would be blue, since the default value for `color` for `a:link` is `blue` and not `inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
div > ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red
}
```

The font-weight and color will apply to all elements inside the ul directly inside your div, unless other styles overwrite them.

Try this:

```
div > ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
div > ul ul {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
}
```

That should make the nested ul not bold, and black instead of red.

Answer (score -2):

It selects direct descendants of the elements, yes. In this case `div > ul`, it selects every ul that is a direct descendant of any div. However it also selects ul's descendants. That is the way this works.

And as explained in the comments, since the font property is being inherited by all of the descendants - you get that.

Comment: it's not technically true to say that is selects the `ul`'s descendents. the selection is contained, but the rule cascades down. another rule which is not inherited by default would apply only to the `ul` and not to its descendents.

Comment: That's what I wanted to say but didn't know how to define the answer properly...Thanks, He should be able to understand it now i think.